# Why does running app.js display Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js

I am coding a bot for Discord and when I run app.js from the cmdbox it keeps saying:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'  
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)  
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)  
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)  
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)  
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Name\Desktop\RoseluckJS\app.js:1:79)  
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)  
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)  
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)  
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)  
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
```

I've already tried to delete the node_modules and then run npm i --save
    discord.js --no-optional again, I have also tried doing npm cache clear then   npm i --save discord.js again but it didn't work. Here is my code for my app.js.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const client = new Discord.client();

        const settings = require('./settings.json');

        client.on('ready',() => {
          console.log('I\'m Online\nI\'m Online')
        });

        client.on('message', message => {
           if (message.content === 'ping') {

           }

        });

        client.login(settings.token);
```

Comment: Could be a number of issues... Did you run npm install from the root of your project where your package.json exists?  After running, did you check for a node_modules folder and see discord in there?

Comment: I did run it from the root of my project @dvsoukup, where my package,json is, but I don't see discord in my node_modules only bufferutil, libsodium-wrappers, opusscript and uws.

Comment: Could you please paste your package.json file.

Comment: Give this a try-  `npm install discord.js --save` then check package.json discord should be there and go for `npm install`.

Comment: @ŁukaszSzewczak here is the package.json   
`{   
  "name": "roseluck",   
  "version": "0.0.1"   ,
  "description": "roseluck bot js bot",   
  "main": "app.js",   
  "scripts": {   
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"   
  },   
  "author": "helperbot",   
  "license": "MIT"   
}`

Ayush,is there supposed to be discord.js inside node_modules after  that? I don't see it

Comment: Ah, never mind I figured out what was wrong for some reason my node wasn't updated but I fixed it. Thanks for the attempts to help though.

Answer (score 0):

On certain versions of windows if you're using shift+right click > context menu > "open command window here". Things get funky, can't explain it, maybe its something with how the paths are handed off from the context menu to the console then to npm install. Alas, if you're using command prompt this way, browse to your c:users\name folder and see if you have a node_modules folder there with discord.js in it. If you find it there (or if you're opening command prompt in this manner), open command prompt as administrator and manually cd into your project folder then try npm install.

I opened an issue on this a while back but the issue was closed. If this answer fixes the issue for you please consider commenting on this issue with something like "i can confirm this issue" or whatever.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16250

Answer (score 0):

If you haven’t done “npm init” then that might be your problem.
Otherwise try “npm install discord.js” instead of i —save.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the discord.js module and reinstalling it with `npm i discord.js —save`